# grep fails looking for string

Tags: command-line, grep

I don't understan why grep doesn't work in the first example

```
bla@ble:~/html/example$ grep -r "protected $disallowedBlockNames = array('install/end');" app/
bla@ble:~/html/example$
```

But

```
bla@ble:~/html/example$ grep -r 'protected $disallowedBlockNames = array' app/

app/Resource/Block.php:    protected $disallowedBlockNames = array('install/end');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide sample input but in your first example your double quotes are allowing the `disallowedBlockNames` variable to be expanded by your shell *before* it is used by `grep`.  I'm assuming this is a variable set in your php code and does not exist in your shell and therefore it is expanding to nothing.  So what you are really sending to grep is:

```
grep -r "protected  = array('install/end');" app/
```

In the second example the single quotes prevent the shell from expanding the variable.

Comment: And grep -re doesn't work either? is there a way to put a $ and still have grep working

Comment: Unless you are intending to perform parameter expansion with the `$` you must escape it either with single quotes or with the ```\``` escape character.